# SQL Server : need add a dot before two last character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a data extracted from a flat file, and I need to add a dot before two last character.

For example

Original table:

```
Price   Discount      Coupon 
-----------------------------
30000    3000         5060  
12500    2050            0  
 5900     590            0  
59000    5900         1000  
 7030       0            0  
37100    5020            0  
21800       0         5060  
 3000    1020            0
```

Transformed table:

```
Price    Discount      Coupon 
-------------------------------
300.00     30.00       50.60  
125.00     20.50        0  
 59.00      5.90        0  
590.00     59.00       10.00  
 70.30      0           0  
371.00     50.20        0  
218.00      0          50.60  
 30.00     10.20        0
```

I tried with the following query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    (LEFT([Price], LEN([Price]) - 2)) + '.' + RIGHT(RTRIM([price]), 2) 
FROM 
    dbo.Rawdata
```

But it only works with the first column

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Thanks so much. . .

Comment: Try a CASE statement: `CASE WHEN LEN([Coupon] > 2 THEN (what you're doing) ELSE … END`

Comment: Looks like XY problem. If those data are numeric just convert to decimal and scale by dividing by 100.

Comment: Do you really want to insert a "dot"?  Or do you want to divide a number by 100 and format the result with 2 places after the decimal?  If the input is "7", do you expect to see "0.07"?   Is this not a value in cents that you are converting to dollar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try add  a check for 0

```
SELECT case when Coupon <> '0' 
     then  (LEFT([Price],LEN([Price] )-2) ) +'.'+RIGHT(RTRIM([price]),2 )  
     else 0 end 
    FROM dbo.Rawdata
```

or

```
SELECT (LEFT([Price],LEN([Price] )-2) )+'.'+RIGHT(RTRIM([price]),2 ) 
FROM dbo.Rawdata
where Coupon <> '0'
```